# Reserve vertical space for slider image on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, flexslider

I'm using Flexslider which calculates the image size based on the parent element width, which makes it responsive because it resizes when you change the browser size.

The problem I'm having is that when I load the page, you see a colapsed slider until the images are loaded which makes it look bad. However, if you go to flexslider site at http://www.woothemes.com/flexslider/ you'll see that it has a loader.

Is there an option in flexslider for automatically behaving this? I couldn't find one.

Comment: use `min-height` and `min-width` for `slider container` ...

Answer (score 1):

Try giving

> min-height

---

> min-width

using CSS to the div block in which you are having the images so that it might atleast not collapse

Answer (score 0):

In flexslider stylesheet they have give `.flexslider` a `min-height` of `280px` and used a gif loading image as its `background`. You should use that. Your problem will be solved.

Comment: The issue is that I have to set the min-height for all the different screen resolutions since I don't know in which device it will be loaded.

Comment: why do you need to set min-height for every resolution? set a minimum min-width. Parent will automatically be re-sized when images are loaded. Or else use jQuery to set dynamic min-width when DOM is ready. Though I will strongly discourage this method. Better to use CSS for min-height.

Comment: I ended up manually setting the height for each resolution, since the slider dimensions will be smaller in smaller screens and I still need the vertical space to be reserved when the page is loaded from a phone